# Get attribute of an object from another class C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a little poker game. In the code below I have a Game class and a Player class. The game class contains a std::vector which contains all the players. The Player class has a name attribute. Now my question is the following: how can I access the Player's attribute name through the vector that contains the Player objects? My problem appears in the last method of the code below, called show().

Thanks for helping!

```
//Player.h

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"

class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    Player(std::string n, double chipsQty);

private:
    const std::string name;
    double chipsAmount;

    Card cardOne;
    Card cardTwo;
};

#endif PLAYER_H

//Player.cpp

#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(){}

Player::Player(std::string n, double chipsQty) : name(n), chipsAmount(chipsQty)
{}

//Game.h

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Player.h"
#include <vector>

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    Game(int nbr, double chipsQty, std::vector<std::string> vectorNames);
    void start();
    void show();

private:
    std::vector<Player> playersVector;
    int nbrPlayers;
};

#endif GAME_H

//Game.cpp

#include "Game.h"
#include "Player.h"

Game::Game(){}

Game::Game(int nbr, double chipsQty, std::vector<std::string> vectorNames) :nbrPlayers(nbr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorNames.size(); i++)
    {
        Player player(vectorNames[i], chipsQty);
        playersVector[i] = player;
    }
}

void Game::start(){};

void Game::show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < playersVector.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << playersVector[i] //Why can't I do something like playersVector[i].name here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget the vector Forget the `Game`. You can't print the name of a single `Player`. That is what you have to figure out. Your question is mainly irrelevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because name attrbute of a Player class is private, so you cannot access it directly from another class. You should add a method to Player class that will return the name of the player, eg:

```
class Player
{
private:
    std::string name; 

public:
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
};
```

Then you can access the player name by

```
playersVector[i].getName()
```

Comment: Or make `name` public. There seems to be no reason for it to be private.